# How to split array of strings (string [])?

Tags: d

I have got array of strings

```
string [] foo
```

array consist next data:

```
2014 01 02 234 124
2014 01 03 640 710
2014 01 04 234 921
```

I need new array of strings date, that would include only date (yyyy-MM-dd). How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a functional approach:

```
string[] dates = foo.map!(line => line.split()[0..3].join("-")).array();
```

Comment: Thanks, but why if I am doing simply:
`datetime = content.split()[0..3];` ?
I am getting error:
`Error: template std.array.split cannot deduce function from argument types !()(string[]), candidates are:`

Comment: You can't split an entire array of strings at once by each line's whitespace, you have to process each line in turn. For that, you can use `for`, `foreach`, or `map` as I used it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your dates always are yyyy MM dd than just slice the string.

translate is in std.string

```
dchar[dchar] translateTable = [' ' : '-'];    
auto dates = foo.map!(line => translate(line[0..10], translateTable));
```